# Assembly language - third element points to

Tags: assembly, mips

would really appreciate if someone can tell me what the third element in the strong list reads.

This is NOT HW, I am merely preparing myself.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kinda hard to do without the part showing how to "decode the following memory layout into a StringLayout as shown above"

Comment: @KonradLindenbach Lindenbach I apologize, I updated it. Please help me understand it.

Comment: @KonradLindenbach do you see the image now?

Comment: +1 This is tough to figure out as some of the definitions, `Head` in particular are worded incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our StringList is a linked list. The 1st pointer goes to the string value of the current element, the 2nd pointer goes to the next node. The head of the list is at location `0x000010000`:

1. at `0x00001000`: `value = ..., next = 0x00003000` (the head element)
2. at `0x00003000`: `value = ..., next = 0x00000010`
3. at `0x00000010`: `value = 0x4024FFA4, next = ...` (our target element)

The string at position `0x4024FFA4` reads `43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 00` which when interpreted as ASCII can be decoded to `"COMPUTER"`. Notice that the byte order at  each address means we have to read the bytes right to left.

Comment: I would agree, except I believe the question itself is worded wrong.  It says to define variable `Head` as a pointer to the first element in the StringList and then asks for the third element - by this reasoning you are only on the second element..  Also, assuming that this system is little endian, the string you have is "COMPUTER" - you have the right letters, but the wrong Endianess.

Comment: @embedded_guy thanks, I just saw my stupid endianess mistake as well. However, the result I found is probably correct – notice the answer under the memory diagram.

Comment: +1 Yep, the question itself is worded wrong.  By the above definitions, you would just get a garbage string at the end.  Assuming that `Head` is just a pointer then makes it point to address `0x00238480` as the first `StringList` element.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that amon has produced the intended answer but I thought that, for the sake of completeness, I would follow the logic as described in the original question.  Again, I believe that the question itself is worded incorrectly and this is why.

1. `Head` is defined as being a pointer/address to the first element in the StringList and `Head` is at address 0x00001000.
2. Therefore, `Head` (defined as a pointer and not a StringList) points to the first element (FirstElement) at `0x00238480`.
3. FirstElement.next is the address to the second element (SecondElement) at `0x0A00C84C`.
4. SecondElement.next is the address to the third element (ThirdElement) at `0x415A494E`.
5. However, from the memory map given, we cannot see what is stored at address `0x415A494E` and therefore, cannot answer the question.