# How to get from code to hex to asci

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm reading up on a question where someone answered: [Assembly language - third element points to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118559/assembly-language-third-element-points-to)

They mentioned
The string at position 0x4024FFA4 reads 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 00 which when interpreted as ASCII can be decoded to "COMPUTER". Notice that the byte order at each address means we have to read the bytes right to left.

I'm trying to see how they got 0x4024FFA4 to 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 00. I'm not sure how they did it. I was able to get hex code to computer using the asci table. but I can't figure out what the string code is

Comment: I don't understand what a "string code" is? The string is "computer\0" which will look like 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 00. Where the string is stored in memory is something that is determined on load of the program. The 'order' the string is stored in memory depends on the architecture. I believe x86/x64 store right to left.

Comment: but how would I go from 0x4024FFA4 to 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really simple. There is no way you can get from pointer (0x4024FFA4) to characters without observing the running program or at least disassembled code (if string is stored at static location).

But generally if you have:

char *mystring;

Then examining mystring in gdb for example, will print pointer, which can be anything (but in their case it was the above address). From there, you get to letters by examining bytes at printed location and following addresses (*(char*)0x4024FFA4, *(char*)0x4024FFA5, and so on).

Added: In a post you linked, you see first column shows memory at address 0x4024FFA4. So you just go there and read characters there.

Comment: how would you go from 0x4024FFA4 to 43 4F 4D 50 55 54 45 52 00 then?

Comment: You go to first column at location marked with address 0x4024FFA4. There you read 0x504d4f43. As this is words printed in little endian, bytes in each word are reversed, so you read them in reverse order. 0x50|4d|4f|43 -> 0x|43|4f|4d|50... Which converted to ASCII is COMP. Higher addresses are printed on top of that. So, 0x52455455 ->reverse order of bytes -> UTER, and the next byte is zero (end of string).

Comment: ahh thanks so much I see it now, how do you know you should just read the first two strings and stop there vs reading less or reading more

Comment: C string always ends with first zero byte and first byte in third word is 0.